# Backup and restore GWC data with minimal downtime

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, copy

I have a geowebcache of for an entire country for 20 zoom level have more than 85 Laksh tiles which is saved in C drive ,I need to move the same file into another system with minimum downtime , traditional copy and paste method take more than 2 days and Re caching is also not possible , is there any way to do that using any specific tool

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see any other options at the moment aside the ones you mention.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no tool. Provide info about your environment. If its linux, zip tilecache folder and transfer to target location with scp command. 25 gb of tiles may occupy 4.5 - 5.5 gb space if you zip it. It may take approx. 30 min - 1 hour to copy into target location & 4-5 hours to unzip, based on your network speed to transfer & system resources to unzip. be ready with all transfer & unzip work in a folder of target system and then initiate downtime. Less downtime will be taken in this way.